# React multi step form with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here.

I'm trying to make a multi-step form to get some details from the user and for some of the nested views, there are only radio buttons. The `handleChange` works fine on text type but how can I handle radio buttons?

React does not render the radio button that is used to render in AngularJS, so I am a bit confused. I can choose multiple radio button and all of them looks like checkboxes instead of choosing only one

**MainForms.js**

```
export class UserForm extends Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    tema: '',
    area: '',
    type: '',
    name: ''
  };

  // Proceed to next step
  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
  };

  // Go back to prev step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };

  // Handle fields change
  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value)
  };

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { area, name, type, tema} = this.state;
    const values = { area, name, type, tema};

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <FormUserDetails
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
             handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
```

**FormUserDetails.js**

```
export class FormUserDetails extends Component {

  continue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  back = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  }

  render() {
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    return (

        <div className="box item2">
          <div className="radio">
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              Basic
            </label>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2R9M.png)

Comment: Can you provide some images about what it should be and what it is right now?

Comment: I have added the link to img. Looks like checkboxes that I can choose both of them

Comment: you have to set the value of your inputs based on the states you have. so after you set you state you have to pass the value of that state to your component. check that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `radio input` not to "work like an checkbox" they all need the same `name` in this case its "yyy".

```js
<div className="box item2">
  <div className="radio">
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="yyy"
        value="123"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      Basic
    </label>
  </div>
  <div className="radio">
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="yyy"
        value="456"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      Basic
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your `handleChange` receives the `event` and not some `input` prop. To see if the `radio input` is checked or not you can use the `checked` property.

```js
handleChange = (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  // do whatever you want with the state :)
  this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value });
};
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I've tried with the ```checked``` also, but strangely says that ```You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler.``` even tho I had ```onChange```.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question correct and if my answer helps you, but what I have made in my solution is something like this:

```
export const RadioButtonInputField = ({label, onChangeOut}) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState(true);

    const setOnChange = (value) => {
       onChangeOut({value: value});

            setState(value);

    };

    return (
      <div className={`dynamic-input-container`}>
          <div className={'radio-button-wrapper'}>
              <p className={'radio-title'}>{label}</p>
              <label className={'radio-label first-radio-label'}>
                  <input
                    type='radio'
                    value={true}
                    checked={state === true}
                    className={'radio-input'}
                    onChange={() => {
                        setOnChange(true);
                    }}                  
                  />
                  <span className={'radio-btn-label'}>Yes</span>
              </label>
              <br />
              <label className={'radio-label'}>
                  <input
                    type='radio'
                    value={false}
                    checked={state === false}
                    className={'radio-input'}
                    onChange={() => {
                        setOnChange(false);
                    }}
                  />
                  <span className={'radio-btn-label'}>No</span>
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I've seen couple of examples uses useState, but since I am using react class component, does not allow me to use that

Comment: Hmmm, okay I'm not strong in class components at all, but you can use setState in your parent component and pass the value into the child component instead of handeling the state in the child component (as I do). Maybe that will work?